# Large raster datasets predictions with R, terra and mlr3: fatal error and session aborted

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster, terra

I try to make predictions on large raster datasets (10–20 band rasters with a size of around 3-6 GB) with terra package, but I always get fatal errors and the R session is aborted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXXJ4.png)

I have autotuned random forest (ranger) models from mlr3 package and 32 GB of RAM in my machine. I work under Windows 10 and R 4.3.2.

Here is the code from prediction with terraOptions(verbose = TRUE):

```
> pred = terra::predict(multiband_raster, model = autotuner_rf)
filename      : C:/Users/Dell 3620/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpqs4XHf/spat_Oo6ZPX1PfuWIttF_2356.tif
compute stats : 1, GDAL: 0, minmax: 0, approx: 1
driver        : GTiff
disk available: 38.6 GB
disk needed   : 0.4 GB
memory avail. : 28.54 GB
memory allow. : 17.12 GB
memory needed : 35.93 GB  (40 copies)
in memory     : false
block size    : 3139 rows
n blocks      : 4
pb            : 3
```

I know that it is a problem with the amount of RAM (I have too little RAM in my machine), but is there another way to make predictions on large raster datasets with only 32 GB of RAM?
I can paste here more information about my R environment, machine, or all of my code.

This data comes mostly from the Sentinel-2 mission, so I tried to make predictions both with reflectance (0.00–1.00 values) and DN (0–10000 values), but even when the multiband raster was smaller (integer with DN values), it did not help.

Comment: You can split the original raster into smaller tiles, then make the predictions on these tiles and finally, mosaic all of the predited tiles to obtain the resulting image. Take a look at `makeTiles`, `split` and `mosaic` functions in the `terra` package.

Comment: There should be no reason to split the raster into tiles. But we do need a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* to show how you might handle this. The example does not need to crash R.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Dear Robert, the way proposed by you on [GitHub](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1386) with adding `wopt=list(steps=10)`  parameter in `predict` function works well. If you want to check the problem with code without this parameter, tell me exactly what you need and in what way I should attach it.